# How can I convert Python unittests to py.test when having global fixtures?

Tags: python, fixtures, pytest, python-unittest, xdist

I do have a set of unit tests written using the Python's *unittest* module. They are using the setUpModule() function to load a global variable with the shared "stuff" that is required to run the tests (including some HTTP sessions).

When running my tests with `unittest`, they are running fine. With `py.test` they are failing.

I patched it a little bit to make it run using the old *pytest* fixture functions (which happen not to have same names as *unittest* ones). It worked, but only when not executed on multiple threads, and that's a feature I do want to use.

The documentation examples are useless in my case because I do have like 20 classes (unittest.TestCase) with 10 tests inside each class. Obviously I do not want to add a new parameter to each test.

Until now I used the class setUp() method to load the shared dictionary inside *self* and use it from there inside each test.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def manager():
    return { "a": "b"}
```

And now the tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# tests.py

class VersionTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.manager = manager

    def test_create_version(self):
        # do something with self.manager
        pass
```

Please remember that I need a solution that would work with multiple threads, calling the fixture a single time.

Answer (score 6):

`pytest` can run `unittest` tests for sure, as documented in [Support for unittest.TestCase / Integration of fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html#unittest-testcase). The tricky part is that using [`pytest` funcargs fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixtures-as-function-arguments) directly is discouraged:

> While pytest supports receiving fixtures via test function arguments for non-unittest test methods, unittest.TestCase methods cannot directly receive fixture function arguments as implementing that is likely to inflict on the ability to run general unittest.TestCase test suites.

Suppose we have a tests module like this, using the standard `unittest` initialization facilities:

```
# test_unittest_tests.py (for the sake of clarity!)
import unittest

manager = None

def setUpModule():
    global manager
    manager = {1: 2}

class UnittestTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.manager = manager

    def test_1_in_manager(self):
        assert 1 in self.manager

    def test_a_in_manager(self):
        assert 'a' in self.manager
```

It yields the following output when ran with `unittest`:

```
$ python -m unittest -v test_unittest_tests
...
test_1_in_manager (test_unittest_tests.UnittestTests) ... ok
test_a_in_manager (test_unittest_tests.UnittestTests) ... FAIL
...
```

The `test_a_in_manager` fails as expected. There isn't any `'a'` key in the `manager` directory.

We set up a conftest.py to provide scoped `pytest` fixtures for these tests. Like this for example, without breaking the standard `unittest` behavior and without the need to touch them tests at all using [`pytest` autouse](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids):

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def manager_session(request):
    # create a session-scoped manager
    request.session.manager = {'a': 'b'}

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def manager_module(request):
    # set the sessions-scoped manager to the tests module at hand
    request.module.manager = request.session.manager
```

Running the tests with `pytest` (using `pytest-xdist`) for parallelization, yields the following output:

```
$ py.test -v -n2
...
[gw1] PASSED test_unittest_tests.py:17: UnittestTests.test_a_in_manager
[gw0] FAILED test_unittest_tests.py:14: UnittestTests.test_1_in_manager
...
```

Now the `test_1_in_manager` fails instead; there isn't any `1` key in the `pytest`-provided manager dictionary.